# Apple TV 720p simulator?

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

In Xcode 8.2.1, I've notice that the option to run tvOS Simulator in 720p screen size is missing. Is there a way to get it back?

This option would be useful since I don't have a 720p television to test my app.

Comment: Was there ever a 720p option?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any difference.

The new Apple TV, runs apps at a standard 1920x1080 resolution at a 1x scale. This means that, when building tvOS apps, the screen size, in points, that you must use when building your interface is also 1920x1080.

As far as screen resolution goes, your application will always be given a 1080p window to draw into, which may be scaled to 720p if needed for output.